# Visual studio debugging starts but application doesn't

Tags: winforms, debugging, visual-studio-2015

So, the problem that I am having is that when I push F5, or click Start, Visual Studio starts debugging, but the application doesn't actually build. If I go to my Task Manager, and look for the process it isn't there. Or, if I alt-tab between the programs I had open. I have had this problem twice now.  The last projet I started, I encountered this problem.  I spent days looking for answers on my time off but couldn't find anyhting. So i started a new project. And now I'm getting the same thing. If I go to my source tree and go back to a previous build and discard my changes, it works fine. But the problem comes back. Its not my coding. I am not getting any build errors. And I don't have any break points. So i can't hit continue. PLease alos note, that between it working, and not working I have not changed ANY setings in Visual Studio. I will post what I have tried. If I forget anything, please forgive me. I have days and days of history to go through in my browser.

1. Restarted Computer and VS
2. Ran VS in Admin
3. Always Build is selected in Tools -> Options -> Projects and
   Solutions -> Build and Run
4. Make sure project is set to Debug in Solution Configuration and
   Build is checked in Configuration Manager.
5. Make sure Only BUild startup projects and dependencies on run is
   unchecked
6. Clean Solution
7. Unchecked Enable the Visual Studio hosting process in Project ->
   Properties -> Debug tab
8. Made sure vshost32.exe was not running in the background while
   program was not running in the Task Manager.
9. Deleted contents of bin and obj files in my project folder file and
   reset computer.
10. Tried running the program from the exe in previously mentioned
     bin/obj file. (The last one does start the process in Task Manager. But still doesnt show in the task bar, or alt tab.)

None of these have worked. I am getting very frustrated at this. Maybe I am not looking for the right thing in Google...

Comment: This could be a stupid question, but is it a solution with only one project or more than one project ? If more than one than check that your project is setup as startproject.

Comment: Never seen anything related to this. Disable your anti-virus program and any other security software. The only logical explanation is that something is killing the process as soon as it tries to start up. Certainly none of this has anything to do with Visual Studio. Don't waste too many more days on it; the problem is your machine. Try a VM first, or just reimage your system.

Comment: @Wiredoncoffee, if you run your app using "start without debugging", does it work normally? I have provided some suggestions for you to narrow down this issue, of course, as Gray's suggestion, you also need to think about your Windows Environment if a simple app still has this issue.

Comment: @JackZhai If I create an empty brand new project, and a blank form, it runs perfetly fine. It comes up. I noticed that now the process is running in my Task Manager (for my project), but it seems to be just my project that it has stopped coming up. Or, stopped working. Kinda wierd. I'm sorry for the lateness of my reply. I also tried reinstalling Visual studio just for giggles. Edit. It seems like it was just one of the forms.  I excluded the most recent one I was working on from my project, and everything started working again. I will just have to figure out what is wrong with the form itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you close all third party tools/processes like the Anti-virus or others, and then re-debug it.

Or

You could run your VS in safemode:

devenv /SafeMode

Some community members found that the symbols loaded is really slow recently, and this issue has been report the Microsoft product team, so please also disable the Microsoft symbols server under TOOLS->Options->Debugging->Symbols. Debug it again.