# Application.Quit - application not starting when debugging

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, visual-studio

When I add Application.Quit(), or Form.Close(), and try running the program with Debugging, the debugging starts, but the Application doesn't. I asked this question yesterday. [Visual studio debugging starts but application doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39383158/visual-studio-debugging-starts-but-application-doesnt/39390774#39390774). And it is a continuation of that question. The process starts in the Task Manager. Its not being caught by my Antivirus.

I can save my project in a state where it is working, add Application.Quit(), start Debugging, and the program wont start. If I comment `//Application.Quit`, so it was the exact same project when it was saved, it still won't start. The only way to fix it, is to exclude the form that has Application.Quit() from the project.  Then it starts working again.  If I add the form back, the problem comes back.

I looked at how to use it properly https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157894(v=vs.110).aspx. I have the FormClosing Event with e.Cancel. I have also tried closing the form `Mainform.Close();` and `Environment.Close()`.  All with the same results. I don't believe that I'm coding it wrong.  There are no errors. But I'm at a loss as to why. It might be my computer. Or I might have to give up on having a warning box before closing. Although ultimately, I would like to have that.

Comment: Can you show **reverent** code of the from that is giving you problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In FormClosing Event if you set `e.Cancel = true` the application will not be closed anyway.

You should use some conditions for `e.Cancel = true`.

Declare a flag parameter and set it before `Application.Quit()` and in FormClosing Event check if the flag is true, then do not set `e.Cancel = true`

Comment: I tried just using a messagebox, which worked. Seemingly working in 1 form seems to be OK instead of trying to work with 2 forms.  Im gonna try this again, now that I have a better idea of what the program is doing. And why it is not starting.